# Error with data returned by ajax cross domain request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am creating an webapp where I need to display infromation on map. But I need to convert the cordinates from EPSG:3301 to EPSG:4326. There is website where you can do it http://spatialreference.org/projection/?json={"geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[527742.81, 6561591.74]}}&inref=EPSG:3301&outref=EPSG:4326 .
So I have my code :

```
$("#btn1").click(function(event){
var searchString    = $('input[name=check_list1]:checked', '#myForm').val();
var data1            = 'search='+ searchString;
if(searchString) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "do_search.php",
        data: data1,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var otsing_data = (data);              
            var json_url = "http://spatialreference.org/projection/?json={'geometry':{'type':'Point', 'coordinates':["+otsing_data['x']+", "+otsing_data['x']+"]}}&inref=EPSG:3301&outref=EPSG:4326";
            $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
                url: json_url,
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                }).done(function (data) {
                var test = data;
                console.log(test);
            });
      }
    });    
} 
//  return false;
})
```

But console.log(test) returns me

```
Object {error: "Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)"}
```

Comment: This error is returned from the API you calling via ajax get method. Console that url and call directly via the browser. You will get the same output.

Comment: What do you mean ? Could you explain it a little more? I need to work with the data I am supposed to get back.

Comment: console.log(json_url); and pul that url in your browser and see what is the result. I think it is the problem with the api calling not with jquery ajax cross domain

Comment: It returns me :  {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [24.485410999999999, 59.191895000000002]} , for example, but I need these coordinates to display the desired location on Google Map. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please check your json_url , is it same? 
I've made same call from console and it is working.

Comment: Please check that data 'otsing_data'. Is it array or Object ? or array of Objects ?

Comment: Thanks for that information, now I can see that the json_url does not provide valid query, but what's the difference? otsing_data is array.. Should I convert it to string first

Comment: Thanks dude, I found that I needed to use " instead of '

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change

```
var json_url = "http://spatialreference.org/projection/?json={'geometry':    {'type':'Point', 'coordinates':["+otsing_data['x']+", "+otsing_data['x']+"]}}&inref=EPSG:3301&outref=EPSG:4326";
```

to

```
var json_url = 'http://spatialreference.org/projection/?json={"geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":['+point_x+', '+point_y+']}}&inref=EPSG:3301&outref=EPSG:4326';
```